# Converting CSV data to string

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, dataframe

So I got a CSV file that has 14 columns, and I was trying to convert that data to string type and I tried this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("2008_data_test.csv", sep=",")
output = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for c in df.columns:
    if df[c].dtype == object:
        print "convert ", df[c].name, " to string"
        df[c] = df[c].astype(str)
    output.to_csv("2008_data_test.csv_tostring2.csv", index=False)
```

This gives me the headers only, and I can't figure out what I missed?

Any ideas? And is it possible to convert specific columns?

Comment: `output = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)` is defined before the `for` loop. That's what you write to CSV; the `for` loop does basically nothing. Did you mean `df.to_csv("2008_data_test.csv_tostring2.csv", index=False)` instead?

Comment: @roganjosh  Oh right!! stupid mistake . thanks it worked !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying one dataframe, but writing another, that's the reason. Use `select_dtypes` instead.

```
c = df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns
df[c] = df[c].astype(str)

df.to_csv("2008_data_test.csv_tostring2.csv", index=False)
```

As [MaxU suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797412/converting-csv-data-to-string/46797508?noredirect=1#comment80544830_46797508), it might be simpler to do filter by `dtypes` in this manner:

```
c = df.columns[df.dtypes.eq('object')]
```

The former creates a dataframe subslice before accessing columns, so this should be cheaper.

---

If you want to convert specific columns only, you can remove columns as needed from `c` before the conversion using `c = c.difference(['Col1', 'Col2', ...])`.

Comment: I'd use `df.columns[df.dtypes.eq('object')]` instead of `df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns` as the latter (`df.select_dtypes(include=[object])`)  first generates a DataFrame and then returns its columns...

Comment: @MaxU that’s great, I didn’t know about that. I’ll edit my answer, or will you write an answer? :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, please feel free to edit your answer ... ;-)